# How to create service in Vue and use all this.$t, this.$alertify etc

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service

I have a service file called message.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    methods:{
        alert(msg,title){            
            this.$alertify.alert( title,msg);   
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And I Use it like below.

```
import messageSvc from '@/shared/services/message'
export default {
  methods:{
     showMessage(){ messageSvc.alert( 'msg', 'title'); }
  }
}
```

This not work, `this.$alertify` is null
My question are:

1. Is this the best way to create service in Vue?
2. Or how to make `this.$alertify` available in my service?

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate @varit05 point, you need to add `vue-alertify` to your Vue instance.  [I have created this example for you](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/oze4/vue-alertify-poc/tree/master/?fontsize=14) using the example alerts that can be found on the [GitHub page for VueAlertify.](https://github.com/sj82516/vue-alertify#how-to-use)

[Here is a GitHub](https://github.com/oze4/vue-alertify-poc) link to the repo containing source code from my example.

This is the important part (should be in your entry point, like `main.js`, which would give your entire app access to that `this.$alertify` "service"):

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueAlertify from "vue-alertify";

Vue.use(VueAlertify);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

If things that you want to access are correctly defined, you can `import Vue from 'vue';` and them acces `Vue.alertify;`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes. It is the best way to create a service/ NPM module.

You can take a reference of [Vuex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex) or [VueAlertify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-alertify) to get more idea.

2. To make it available globally to all the Vue components, you need to call the global method `Vue.use(plugin_name/service_name)`. In your case, it is $alertify then it should be as below

I believe you're using [VueAlertify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-alertify)

> import VueAlertify from 'vue-alertify';
>
> Vue.use(VueAlertify);

However, you need to register the plugin/Service before Vue Instance is invoked.

Official docs for [Plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin)

Hope this helps!